# Is there a way to crosswalk coordinates and zip codes in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, zipcode

I have latitude/longitude data for building permits in the City of Chicago, and I am hoping to crosswalk them to zip codes. I have a list of all Chicago zip codes that I can use, but am unsure of how to broach this problem.

I have two variables, `chi_zips_map`, which contains geospatial data via the `tigris` package, and `mapping_data_19`, which contains my lat/long data.

I have been able to successfully map both the zip codes and lat/long data using leaflet using the following code:

```
chi_zips_map %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(weight = '0.5', color = 'purple') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = mapping_data_19, 
                   lng = ~longitude, 
                   lat = ~latitude, 
                   radius = 2, 
                   color = ~permitpal(permit_type))
```

and have gotten the following map, which is great:

[Map of points.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvKP.png)

Is it possible for me to add a zip code column in the `mapping_data_19` data frame based off the processes I've done so far?